# += operator in Scala

Tags: scala, operators

I'm reading Programming in Scala by M. Odersky and now I'm trying to understand the meaning of operators. As far as I can see, any operator in Scala is just a method. Consider the following example:

```
class OperatorTest(var a : Int) {

  def +(ot: OperatorTest): OperatorTest = {
    val retVal = OperatorTest(0);
    retVal.a = a + ot.a;
    println("=")
    return retVal;
  }
}

object OperatorTest {
  def apply(a: Int) = new OperatorTest(a);
}
```

I this case we have only + operator defined in this class. And if we type something like this:

```
var ot = OperatorTest(10);
var ot2 = OperatorTest(20);
ot += ot2;
println(ot.a);
```

then

```
=+
30
```

will be the output. So I'd assume that for each class (or type?) in Scala we have `+=` operator defined for it, as `a += b iff a = a + b`. But since every operator is just a method, where the += operator defined? Maybe there is some class (like `Object` in Java) containing all the defenitions for such operators and so forth.

I looked at `AnyRef` in hoping to find, but couldn't.

Answer (score 12):

`+=` and similar operators are desugared by the compiler in case there is a `+` defined and no `+=` is defined. (Similarly works for other operators too.) Check the Scala Language Specification ([6.12.4](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#assignment-operators)):

> Assignment operators are treated specially in that they can be
>   expanded to assignments if no other interpretation is valid.
>
> Let's consider an assignment operator such as += in an infix operation
>   l += r, where l, r are expressions. This operation can be
>   re-interpreted as an operation which corresponds to the assignment
>
> l = l + r except that the operation's left-hand-side l is evaluated
>   only once.
>
> The re-interpretation occurs if the following two conditions are
>   fulfilled.
>
> The left-hand-side l does not have a member named +=, and also cannot
>   be converted by an implicit conversion to a value with a member named
>   +=. The assignment l = l + r is type-correct. In particular this implies that l refers to a variable or object that can be assigned to,
>   and that is convertible to a value with a member named +.